# Get code to $_POST variable php

Tags: php, variables

```
$newRequesterPass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
$static_salt = 'M0AaE|}{<}|{&*@^AhEQ'; 
$dynamic_salt = mt_rand(); 
$newRequesterPass = sha1($dynamic_salt . $password . $static_salt);

$newRequesterDynamSalt = $_POST($dynamic_salt);
```

I get error:  `Function name must be a string`

How do I get this code to `$_POST` correctly:

```
$newRequesterDynamSalt = $_POST($dynamic_salt);
```

Comment: Walley, $_POST is **not** a function.

Comment: "Get this code to `$_POST` correctly"? You mean you want to add a new element to `$_POST`?

Comment: You use `$_POST` correctly as an array in your first variable initialization.  Why change to a function call at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array, you access arrays with [], so:

```
$_POST[$dynamic_salt]
```

But, it seems you confused server side and client side into one script.
The fix I gave is just for the specific error, not for the algorithm u try to implement.